# Cannot import milp from scipy

Tags: python, scipy, package

I am new to python and I wanted to try out the [milp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html#scipy.optimize.milp) (mixed integer linear programming) tool from scipy. So I use the same line as in the tutorial to import it

`from scipy.optimize import milp`

However, it gives me the error
 `from scipy.optimize import milp ImportError: cannot import name 'milp' from 'scipy.optimize' (C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py)`

I have the latest scipy version 1.10.1 in my python interpreter. What is going wrong?

I tried different versions of the scipy package and also googling the error.

Comment: The error you encountered suggests that the `milp` function is not available in the `scipy.optimize` module. This is because `milp` is not a built-in function in SciPy. The `scipy.optimize` module primarily focuses on continuous optimization and does not provide specific support for mixed integer linear programming (MILP).

If you want to solve MILP problems in Python, you can consider using specialized libraries such as PuLP, Pyomo, or Gurobi that provide more comprehensive support for MILP.

Comment: In the document they are importing from `from scipy.optimize import milp`. Link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html

Comment: It is working on my google colab. `from scipy.optimize import milp` `scipy.__version__` `1.10.1`

Comment: @edamondo colab is `Python 3.10.11` . I would suggest to install python `3.10` and then try. I see you are using `python 3.9`

Comment: @GodIsOne, thank you for the suggestion, now it works, when I upgraded Python to 3.10.11!

Comment: @edamondo If this problem is solved then you can close this question.